# Name requires more than 30 bytes in LATIN internal form?

Tags: java, jdbc, teradata

I am trying to implement `Fastload Utility` with jdbc. But I keep getting the following error: **`Name requires more than 30 bytes in LATIN internal form`**

I read many articles : this error occurs during table creation. **In my case this error is thrown at the `executeBatch()` line .** Here is my code

```
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password); // I am using TYPE=FASTLOAD 
    // creating table 
    String createStr = 
    "CREATE TABLE dbname.tablename( " + 
" Fname VARCHAR(506) CHARACTER SET UNICODE, " + 
" Lname VARCHAR(507) CHARACTER SET UNICODE " + 
" );"
    Statement createTable  = ... 
    createTable.execueQuery("CREATE TABLE ... ") ;

    PreparedStatement prst = ...  ; 


    while ( // loop ) { 
    prst.addBatch();
    }
    prst.executeBatch(); // Here it throws this error 
    conn.commit();
```

Why do I get this error when `executeBatch()` method fires ? What can I do ?

Comment: I guess the answer is somewhere hidden in the `...` parts you left out.

Comment: Yup, we need the full `CREATE TABLE` clause

Comment: I tried a dataset that has 200K rows and it failed. Then I reduced the number of rows in the same dataset and it worked. Generally it works fine, it is just this dataset doesn't work. Also, why `executeBatch()` would throw such an error ? All articles online say that the `create ` statement throws this error, but why `executeBatch() `failed in my case , but not the `create`

Comment: @Andrew i pasted the create clause

Comment: Well, that looks pretty harmless. Anyhow, just managed to notice you're saying it happens in the executeBatch.  Make sure none of the column names referenced there are more than 28 characters.

Comment: @Andrew I thought that the table name should be `26` characters maximum because of the `_ERR ` tables . I always thought that the maximum length of the teradata columns is `30`

Comment: @Andrew It worked !!! Why `28` ? What is the max length of columns and table name ? Please post an answer so that I could accept it Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe FastLoad prefaces the column names with "F_", so your column names need to be 28 characters or less.
From the documentation:

```
The destination table column names must not exceed 28 characters.
```

Here's a link to the [documentation](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html#BABFGFAF).